# Why does the converse of mean value theorem hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function and $z_0\in G$. Then, how do I prove that there exist $z,w\in G$ such that $f'(z_0)=\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$?

This problem was on an exam and I tried to find a solution for hours, but nothing really worked. My friend told me it can be proven using Rouche's theorem but I do not get it.

Comment: The comment about Liouville's theorem was somewhat tongue-in-cheek. Anyway you want to find a way to rephrase the problem in terms of finding zeros of a certain function. The fact that $f'$ is also holomorphic is probably relevant. I vaguely remember having seen something similar to this before, but I don't remember the answer right now and thus understand quite well how you are confused by this problem. If I remember or figure it out myself I will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ in nonconstant and holomorphic in $D(0,r).$ Assume $f(0) = 0.$

Case i): $f'(0)=0.$ Then the order of the zero of $f$ at $0$ is some $m\ge 2.$ A well known result then tells us there is an open set $U,$ with $0 \in U\subset D(0,r),$ such that $f$ is exactly $m$-to-$1$ in $U\setminus \{0\}.$ Thus there exist $z,w \in U,z\ne w,$ such that $f(z)=f(w).$ Hence we get $(f(z)-f(w))/(z-w) = 0 = f'(0).$

Case ii): $f'(0)\ne 0.$ There are two possibilities: $f(z) = f'(0)z,$ for which the result is trivial, and $f(z) = f'(0)z + g(z)$ where $g\not \equiv 0.$ In the latter sub case we can apply i) to $g$ to obtain $z,w \in D(0,r),z\ne w,$ such that $g(z)=g(w).$ This gives $(f(z)-f(w))/(z-w) = f'(0).$

The result for general $G$ follows from this.